# How did Tally know beforehand that they found Amelia?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-nice-guys

In the movie, *The Nice Guys* (2016), Tally calls Jackson and Holland and tells them that Judith wanted $100,000 in cash. Then Holland tells her that they found Amelia, and Tally tells them that she will send the family doctor. Then she wants to get Holland and Jackson out of the house, so she asks if they will deliver the money personally.

But why did she call them in the first place? Did she know before hand that they found Amelia, and her entire purpose was to get them out of the house?

Also, Tally was the one that hired John Boy right?

Answer (score 2):

Tally knows that Amelia has met Jackson and Holland. She needs them to leave Amelia unprotected. Tally knows that Holland has a crush on her. She uses that to convince Holland to take the $100,000 and go personally to deliver it.

Then under the guise of the family doctor, Tally sends John Boy to take out Amelia.